# Error creating bean with name '..' defined in file ..xml

Tags: java, spring

can you help me please? 1.My Dao

```
package user.dao.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import user.domain.DboBean;

public class DboDao {
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public DboDao() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        DataSource datatSource = transactionManager.getDataSource();
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datatSource);
    }

//Spring setter injector used
public void setTransactionManager(DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager){
    this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
}


public DboBean read() {//String dboId
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql = "SELECT ins_ID, ins_name FROM da_tracking "
            + "WHERE ins_ID = 3";
    final Object[] params = new Object[] {};//dboId

    //Creating object being queried
    final DboBean dboBean = new DboBean();      
    //Process query Results
    jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new RowCallbackHandler(){
        public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
            dboBean.setDboId(rs.getString("dboId"));    
        }

    });
    return dboBean;//returns queried objects
}
}
```

2. My Bean:

```
 package user.domain;

 public class DboBean {

    private String dboId;
    private String dboDevName;

    public DboBean(){
        this.setDboId(dboId);
        this.setDboDevName(dboDevName);     
    }

    public String getDboId() {
        return dboId;
    }

    public void setDboId(String dboId) {
        this.dboId = dboId;
    }

    public String getDboDevName() {
        return dboDevName;
    }

    public void setDboDevName(String dboDevName) {
        this.dboDevName = dboDevName;
    }
 }
```

My spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XYDB" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="xyz" />            
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="objDbo" class="user.dao.impl.DboDao">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

And my Junit:

```
package user.dao.JUnitTest;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import java.lang.Object;

import user.dao.impl.DboDao;
import user.domain.DboBean;


public class JUnitDaoTest extends TestCase {
private static final String OID = "dboId";
private static final String DDN = "dboDevName";
protected static ApplicationContext appContext;
private DboDao objDao;

public JUnitDaoTest(String arg) {
    super(arg);
}

public static Test suite(){
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
    suite.addTest(new JUnitDaoTest("testDboDAO"));
    return suite;       
}

public void setUp() throws Exception{
    init();
    objDao =  (DboDao) getBean("objDao");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
}
//@Override
public synchronized void init(){
    if (appContext == null){
        try{
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");

            String configDir = path + slash + "config" + slash;
            DOMConfigurator.configure(configDir +  "log4j.xml");

            appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {configDir + "appContext.xml"});
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

protected Object getBean(String beanName){
    return appContext.getBean(beanName);
}


public void testDboDAO(){
    DboBean record = new DboBean();
    record.setDboId(OID);//setDboId(dboId);
    record.setDboDevName(DDN);



    DboBean bean = objDao.read();
    assertEquals(DDN, bean.getDboDevName());
    System.out.println("User selected [" + bean.getDboId() + ", " + bean.getDboDevName() + 
            "]");

    //objDao.delete(dboId);
    //bean = objDao.read(dboId);
    //assertEquals(null, bean.getDboDevName());
    //System.out.println("User is deleted [" + bean.getDboId() + ", " + bean.getDboDevName() + 
        //  "]");

}
```

}

I get this Error:
Error creating bean with name 'objDbo' defined in file [...\config\appContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [user.dao.impl.DboDao]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.l

Have you an idea??
blob

Answer (score 3):

The stacktrace will explain the exact problem, it will be in whatever follows the "nested exception is java.l..." part of the stacktrace you cut off. Read the whole error message.

If I were to take a guess, your `DboDao` class has a null pointer exception in the constructor because you are referring to a field `transactionManager` that is not set yet.

I'd suggest writing a unit test of this `DboDao` class - which doesn't involve Spring at all - to test what happens when you call `new DboDao()`.

Also you might find it convenient to have your DAO class just extend the Spring utility class [`JdbcDaoSupport`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html).

Comment: Sorry..' nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: Right - so the problem is that you have a NullPointerException in the constructor of your class. The constructor as you posted will never work, and will always throw an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataSourceTransactionManager  is not set when it is used in the constructor. This will result in an NPE when Spring is setting up your context.

You can alternately just dependency inject the JdbcTemplate as your transaction manager is not being used except to set up your JdbcTemplate. If, for whatever reason, you dont want to configure your JdbcTemplate, you can use an [init method](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/) to build it (as it will be called after Spring supplies all dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DboDao {
private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public DboDao() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    // problem exists here, as transactionManager is not set yet and
    // you are using Setter Based injection so `NPE`
    // you can move this code in setter method of transactionManager, to make it work. 
    DataSource datatSource = transactionManager.getDataSource(); 
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datatSource);
}.............
```

Also, I see wrong things in your code. Use transaction manager at service layer. And inject dataSource in DboDao. And create jdbcTemplate like as below:

```
public class DboDao {
private DataSource dataSource;  // either use @Autowire or provide xml config
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public DboDao() {        
    super();        
}
....// getter and setter for jdbcTemplate and dataSource

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Looking at your configuration file, if you want to make your app run: intialize dataSource and jdbcTemplate in setter methods, as you are using setter based injection.

```
public class DboDao {
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public DboDao() {
        super();            
    }

//Spring setter injector used
public void setTransactionManager(DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager){
    this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    // moved code from constructor
    DataSource datatSource = transactionManager.getDataSource(); 
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datatSource);
}
```